# Logging in Web role MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, logging, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. I need to be able to log controller logic.

Now i have created a Windows Azure project and added a web role and added this web application as a web-role.

How can I log when the the website is running as a cloud service?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Diagnostics enables you to collect diagnostic data from a worker role or web role running in Windows Azure.

The Windows Azure diagnostic monitor runs in Windows Azure and in the compute emulator to collect diagnostic data for a role instance. Log data will be periodically saved to a storage account where it can be examined.

For step-by-step instructions refer to [Enabling Diagnostics in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/).

For additional information refer to [Collect Logging Data by Using Windows Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx), [Diagnostics and Debugging in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694035.aspx) and [Windows Azure Diagnostics–From the Ground Up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/golive/archive/2012/04/21/windows-azure-diagnostics-from-the-ground-up.aspx).

For advanced dianostic management features check [Azure Diagnostics Manager](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-diagnostics-manager/introduction) (free trial available).